# Useragent in PHP scraper script

Tags: php

I have a PHP scraper script which I use to scrape a page on my site. The script then parses the content into HTML and outputs it for the user. I came across using the useragent function in PHP to pretend that you are a crawler, for example GoogleBot. How can I combine my two scripts together so the page I am scraping thinks I am a crawler?

My scraper PHP code is:

```
$query=$_REQUEST['q'];

$html = file_get_contents("search.php?q=$query");
preg_match_all(
    '/<div class="cl1 cld">.*?<a rel="nofollow" class="l le" href="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a>.*?<div class="cra">(.*?)<\/div>.*?<div class="clud">(.*?)<\/div>.*?<\/div>/s',
    $html,
    $posts, // will contain the blog posts
    PREG_SET_ORDER // formats data into an array of posts
);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $link = $post[1];
    $title = $post[2];
    $description = $post[3];
    $url = $post[4];

echo "<div class='result'><div class='title'><a href='$link'>$title</a></div>$description<div class='url'>$url</div></div>";
}

?>
```

I have this line of code which pretends to be a crawler.

```
$userAgent = 'MyScraperBot (http://www.mysite.com/)';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep using [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) you can set PHPs internal (http fopen wrapper) user-agent with:

```
 ini_set("user_agent", 'MyScraperBot (http://www.mysite.com/)');
```

Comment: On top of the file, before the file_get_contents call.

Comment: Before you send any file request.

Comment: It will show up in the log files. If that webmaster checks the access log for user-agents, then that's what he'll see.

Comment: Yes, here's a list of user agents you can pretend to be: http://www.user-agents.org/

Comment: It will show up as whatever you set the user_agent value to, but if you are trying to be a specific bot then that list will have the correct value for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CURL [setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

```
// spoofing FireFox 2.0
$useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";

$ch = curl_init();

// set user agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
// set the rest of your cURL options here
```

Comment: Just put any user agent you want, like your own.